# I am trying to create a batch file for running commands on my router but cannot get past the enable password

Tags: batch-file, cmd, passwords, router, plink

I have the current script written to get me into the router.

```
"plink.exe" -ssh username@host -pw password < "input.txt"
```

The problem is once I am in the router I need it to enable and then enter another password in before I can execute commands. When I run this script it gets to the enable part but does not enter in the password.  From what I am understanding in my "input.txt" I have the command "enable" which it executes, but if I put anything after that it runs it as a new command. After I enter in the "enable" command I need it to enter a password before executing more commands and I can't just put it right underneath "enable" in the "input.txt."

Is there a way to fix this?

Here is the input.txt I have set up

```
enable
password
config t
(I would like to enter different commands here once in configuration mode)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In UNIX systems you can use the `expect` command for this. See if you can install a port of it to windows. Maybe from Mingw or cygwin.

Comment: I will look into that. If I was to use expect where would I put into the script? I am unfamiliar with the expect command. @konsolebox

Comment: Expect is more a scripting language so you'd have to look for tutorials and examples on how to use it. It's like a shell as well but is more adept at handling output and controlling input of called processes.

Comment: The password is not a command. It's input of the `enable` "command". So, see [How to pass user input automatically using plink.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34477728/850848).

Comment: I do not your commands/router. But I assume you want to put `enable`, `password`, `config t` lines (+ something like `exit`) to the `input.txt`.

Comment: In your question above, you do not have that. You have `-m "commands file"`, that's not the same as `< "commands file"`. Also, you have `Echo` in each line, what is wrong in either case. So are you saying that neither `< "commands file"` works (without the `echo`s)? Then please edit your question to say that you have tried that, what exactly does your command file look like and give us way more detailed description of the behavior.

Comment: I have corrected the description of behavior. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions or comments. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: *"but if I put anything after that it runs it as a new command"* – it does not, not in the case of `<` (it's true for `-m` only). – What exactly happens? Does it get stuck on the password prompt? Where *exactly* is the cursor? Post a screenshot. – Three things to try 1) Try adding `-t` or `-T` to Plink command-line. 2) Try unix line ending in the "command file" 3) Try delaying the `password` input, see [Wait between sending login and commands to serial port using Plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55851109/850848).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass user input automatically using plink.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477728/how-to-pass-user-input-automatically-using-plink-exe)